# JQuery remove div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this in my html and i want to remove the divs with `ad spf-nolink` classes

```
<div class="ad spf-nolink">
<ol id="search-results" class="result-list context-data-container">
<div class="ad spf-nolink">
```

I try to do it with:

```
var adElem = $('#ad spf-nolink');
if (adElem == null) {
    alert('1');
} else {
    $("#ad spf-nolink").removeClass();

    alert('3');
}
```

And the 2 `divs` are still there,Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Removing classes is not the same as removing elements. Which do you want?

Comment: no element has the `pyv-afc-ads-container` class and why are you using an id selector for the class `ad`

Comment: Just as an FYI, to check if the element exists, check the jQuery superset DOM Object's length property like so `if(adElem.length)`...

Comment: @isherwood I want to remove the two div with the ad spf-nolink class

Comment: `$('.ad.spf-nolink').remove()` or `$('.ad.spf-nolink').detach()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You selector is wrong .

```
var adElem = $('.ad.spf-nolink').removeClass('ClassName');
```

[**.** class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

[**#** id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
$('.ad.spf-nolink').removeClass('pyv-afc-ads-container spf-nolink');
```

Comment: You don't need two declarations for removeclass ...

Answer (score 0):

you've got a bit of confusion on the use of jQuery selectors ... however

```
var adElem = $('.ad.spf-nolink');
if (adElem.length > 0) {
  //element exist remove class "spf-nolink"
  adElem.removeClass("spf-nolink");
} else {
  //if you need something in case of no element with ad class is also spf-nolink
}
```

you can do the same for remove "pyv-afc-ads-container" class... using corrent selector

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
$('.ad.spf-nolink').remove();
```

Or if you want to remove only div classes you can do:

```
$('.ad.spf-nolink').removeClass('ad');
$('.ad.spf-nolink').removeClass('spf-nolink');
```